# How to disable password change for openldap user?

Tags: ldap, openldap

Considering possible solutions for some improvements I run into this theoretical question and I couldn't find a satisfying answer. Some of you may have first-hand experience with this in practice, so here the question goes:

How can I disable password changing for an OpenLDAP user?

The account must stay enabled, allowed to log on to workstations and work as usual, but should not be able to change its own password.
Can this be done?
If so, how difficult is it to implement it?

All suggestions are appreciated!

For reference: Servers and workstations are to run a mixture of FreeBSD and OpenBSD. Accounts to get password disabled are student or generic workstation accounts. Environment is a school.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very clear what you want to do, but  you can try to use [OpenLDAP ACLs](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/access-control.html) to create the restrictions you need.

Usually, the ability to modify a password is restricted to `self` and administrators, but you can limit this further for certain OUs.

Comment: This looks promising. As far as I can see, OpenLDAP ACLs can allow me to set up user accounts where the user itself has read-only access to its own password (which would allow the user to log on to workstations) but cannot change the password. At the same time, an OpenLDAP administrator could still be able to  modify/update/change the password for such an account. Which is something I am after.

Comment: Yes, exactly. These ACLs can get a bit difficult to get right sometimes, but in the end, they are quite powerful.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to implement the password policy overlay. That gives you a lot of control over passwords, including different rules for different groups of users.

Comment: This sounds good enough to investigate further. Can you please provide a link to where it is documented or an exampe/howto somewhere!

Comment: Just search for 'man slapo-ppolicy'. It's all there at OpenLDAP.org.

Comment: Nice. I will need to check if it works on the BSDs, though. Thanks!